# Filter array of objects with conditions

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an array like this:

```
const myArray = [
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 1, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 0, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 0, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 1, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, type: "group" },
];
```

The new array should filter by unique ageIndex, but only when the type is `group`. The other objects of type `person` should stay unchanged. The `nameIndex` doesn't matter. There are group objects without a nameIndex.

```
const myNewArray = [
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 1, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 0, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 1, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, type: "group" },
];
```

How can I filter it like that?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the nameIndex, i hope this could help:

```js
const myArray = [
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 1, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 0, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 0, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 1, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, type: "group" },
];

const filterSameGroup = arr => {
  const ageIndexes = [];
  return arr.filter(item => {
    if(item.type === "group") {
      if(ageIndexes.indexOf(item.ageIndex) != -1) {
        return false;
      }
      ageIndexes.push(item.ageIndex);
      return true;
    } 
    return true;
});
}

console.log(filterSameGroup(myArray));
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast help! This is it! I had filtered it the wrong way and filtered the person also. But this works now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = [
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 1, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 4, nameIndex: 0, type: "group" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 0, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, nameIndex: 1, type: "person" },
    { ageIndex: 5, type: "group" },
];

var filtered = myArray.filter(function(value) {
  return value.type === "group" && value.ageIndex >= 5;
});
```